# TfIdf vectorizer returning positive values for absent words

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm vectorizing a corpus using the TfIdf vectorizer in sklearn. The corpus is large, but the data more or less looks like this:

```
index speaker text
1     Bob     'this is sample text'
2     Dick    'also some sample words but different ones'
3     Jane    'stuff goes here that did not go above'
4     Mary    'my name is mary and my text is not being analyzed'
```

I want to find how the TfIdf values for words break down by speaker for the first three speakers. So I have:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stemmed_stops)
word_vec = vec.fit_transform(df.loc[['Bob', 'Dick', 'Jane'], 'text'])
```

After vectorizing the corpus, I created a dataframe with the TfIdf values whose columns are the vocabulary:

```
speaker_vocab = pd.DataFrame(word_vec.toarray(), index=['Bob', 'Dick', 'Jane'], columns = vec.vocabulary_)
```

This gives a dataframe that looks like:

```
    this  sample   that  my  text ...
Bob  0.5    0.3  0.0   0.0   0.5
```

The problem is that speakers who never use certain terms are getting positive TfIdf values for those terms. For instance, if I look at the words for Jane, I get:

```
In: df.loc['Jane'].sort_values(ascending=False)
Out:
sample 0.32
goes .14
text .11
```

This seems to happen for all speakers, and words are positive that never appear in their row. The positive values differ, but they remain positive.

In general, is there a reason the vectorizer would return positive values for words not in the same speaker rows?

Comment: Please show the data in the column `'stems'`

Comment: @VivekKumar for the purposes of this question, `stems` was a typo on my part. i just removed the entire portion of code that involves stemming for this question. thanks for flagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the columns param wrong in

```
speaker_vocab = pd.DataFrame(word_vec.toarray(), 
                             index=['Bob', 'Dick', 'Jane'], 
                             columns = vec.vocabulary_)
```

As per [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> vocabulary_ : dict
>
> ```
> A mapping of terms to feature indices.
> ```

Dicts can return items in arbitrary order. So this `dict` may (will) not give the names in same order as the data returned in `word_vec`.

To get the names in exact order, use `vec.get_feature_names()`.

```
speaker_vocab = pd.DataFrame(word_vec.toarray(), 
                             index=['Bob', 'Dick', 'Jane'], 
                             columns = vec.get_feature_names())
```

After that you will get the correct output.

```
speaker_vocab.loc['Jane'].sort_values(ascending=False)

#Output:
stuff        0.5
goes         0.5
go           0.5
above        0.5
words        0.0
this         0.0
text         0.0
sample       0.0
ones         0.0
```